# Awk output unmatched rows

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have awk command to output matched rows data comparing on 2 columns,
although I would like to output the opposite, unmatched data.

```
#file1.csv
box1,apple
box2,banana


#file2.csv
data24,box1,apple,text
date25,box1,banana,text
```

And by AWK I have,

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($2,$3) in a' file1.csv file2.csv
```

The output looks like:

```
data24,box1,apple,text
```

And would like to have:

```
banana,box2
```

Simple negation seems does not work in this case, do you have any ideas please?
Have tried :

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=1; next} !($2,$1) in a' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Which will output:

```
data24,box1,apple,text
date25,box1,banana,text
```

Comment: (a) the `awk` script you've posted does not produce the indicated output. (b) you're looking for `($2,$3) in a`, but e.g. in `file2.csv`, `$3` is `date24` or `date25`, which will never be `in a`. I think you're using the wrong columns.

Comment: sorry, updated with current version

Comment: I don't know `awk` that well, but can't you replace `==` by `<>` or `!=`?

Comment: I get no output at all after trying your code (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: https://ctrlv.link/wEgr , please verify the input (Ubuntu20.04.02)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the "simple negation" you tried to use that did not work. The expected output you posted would require doing more than just `output the opposite, unmatched data`, e.g. it doesn't print the file2 values that do not appear in file1, and it prints different fields in a different order from your currently working command. So, please make sure the expected output you posted is exactly what you want given the input you posted (and get rid of the blanks you've added after the `,`s if you don't really want those added).

Comment: Look at your "negated" script - you've changed `a[$1,$2]` to `a[$1,$2]=1`  (which does nothing but use up processor cycles and memory) and changed `($2,$3)` to `($2,$1)` which completely changes what you're comparing. if you hadn't done any of that then just adding the `!` would have actually been negating your original script and produced output more like what you want. It's still not clear why `banana,box2` would be your expected output instead of `date25,box1,banana,text` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$2,$3]; next} !(($1,$2) in a){print $2, $1}' file2.csv file1.csv
banana,box2
```

Comment: Thank you Ed! Your answer was the cleanest to perform and easy to use :)

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- both files are comma delimited
- find lines from `file1.csv` that do not have a match with fields #2 and #3 from `file2.csv`
- for such entries (from `file1.csv`) print the fields in reverse order (OP has shown  final output of `banana,box2`, which is the reverse order of `box2,banana` as listed in `file1.csv`)

A few modifications to OP's `awk` code:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { a[$1 FS $2] ; next }           # add a delimiter to allow for splitting of index later
        { delete a[$2 FS $3] }           # delete file #1 entries if found in file #2
END     { for (i in a) {                 # anything left in array was not found in file #2
              split(i,arr,FS)            # split index on delimiter
              print arr[2],arr[1]        # print fields in reverse order
          }
        }
' file1.csv file2.csv
```

This generates:

```
banana,box2
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reversing the logic, you can reverse the action:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($2,$3) in a {next}1' file1.csv file2.csv
date25,box1,banana,text
```

Or:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($2,$3) in a {next} {print $2, $3}' file1.csv file2.csv
box1,banana
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: That comment is BS for several reasons: 1) The code used is the OP's code with an obvious minor change that fixes his problem and 2) the minor change IS commented with *Instead of reversing the logic, you can reverse the action* which is both responsive to his question and the answer itself and 3) You are being petty and mechanical.